# Express js event list?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I tried to find in the official documentation but have found no list of events for express.

Is there such a thing like `'route-matched'` so I can do `app.on('route-matched', () => {})`?

Edit: in the official page, there was `mount` event, which is called when sup app mount on parent app. Beside this there is no link no information where to find the supported events.

Comment: `have found no list of events` - not even `mount`?

Comment: I meant the list, mount was the only thing there.

Comment: do you know of any others?

Comment: From some other SO questions, there are `finish` and `close`, but couldn't get `close` to work. I got `finish` work for me though

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you refer to the Nodejs http.ServerResponse events?

As stated in the [Express js docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res):

> The res object is an enhanced version of Node’s own response object and supports all built-in fields and methods.

And then in the [Node js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse):

> Class: http.ServerResponse:
>
> - Event: 'close'
> - Event: 'finish'

Answer (score 4):

I created a barebones app that I created using the command:

```
 npm install -g express-generator
 express myExpressApp --view pug
```

This generated (amongst other things) a file called `bin/www`, which contains the following lines:

```
server.listen(port)
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
```

...

```
/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Using VS Code, I placed a breakpoint at the beginning of the `onListening` function. When I started debugging the app, I was able to look into the code that triggered the `listening` event. I found a script called `<node_internals> net.js`, which contains calls to `emit` the following events:

- 'connect'
- 'connection'
- 'close'
- 'error'
- 'listening'
- 'lookup'
- 'ready'
- 'timeout'

Details of these (and other) events can be found in the [Node.js Documentation for Net](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html).

The `mount` event is generated in the file `node_modules/express/lib/application.js`, which might explain why it is the only one explicitly documented for ExpressJS, although your `express` app object can be trained to handle others.

[mount](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.onmount)

There is nothing like a `route-matched` event though... but I guess that by now you will have found a workaround : )

Answer (score 1):

Having looked at the docs, I found

[mount](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.events)

and nothing else.

Looking at the source code, I found nothing other than one call to emit said mount event. The code base *isn't* all that big, though perhaps some of the dependencies are themselves event emitters that will do things you could potentially listen for, though I don't think most of them are actually exposed.

So I guess what I'm saying is that you found the only list of events in the documentation that there is, because there's only one event that's emitted from Express.

That said, I am curious why you want to listen for a route being matched?  Middleware attached to that route will fire when it's matched, so that's as much of a listener as you'd want.

Comment: There is some functions I only want to run when a route is matched. Using middleware i will have to do 1 of following 2 bad things in this case:
1. Run on every route, doesn't matter match or not 
2. call the function in every route

Either way I don't feel like it will be good in long run

Comment: ? I'm not following.  If you do something like, `app.use('/route/to/match`, myFunction(){});` it'll only run when '/route/to/match' is matched. Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

The return value from the [`app.listen`](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.listen) method is a [Server](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#class-netserver) instance. It contains these events that can be listened to using the `server.on` method:

- [Event: 'close'](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#event-close)
- [Event: 'connection'](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#event-connection)
- [Event: 'error'](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#event-error)
- [Event: 'listening'](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#event-listening)
- [Event: 'drop'](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#event-drop)

The [`Socket`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#class-netsocket) class has other [events](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#event-close_1) that could be listened to. This could be obtained through the `connection` event of the `Server` instance.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps, it is a superset of https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

However, it is safer to do

```js
const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT)  // server is an instance of http.Server
server.on('close', callback)
```